# Python + Selenium: How to pass a function into @pytest.mark.parametrize?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I use Selenium + Python and I need a parametrized test for testing images but got an error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute_script'` This is my code:

```
# get list of images
def get_images_list(driver):
    images_list = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('img')")
    return images_list

# test every image
@pytest.mark.parametrize("image", get_images_list(driver))
def test_images(driver, image):
    driver.get('https://openweathermap.org/')
    image_check = driver.execute_script("return (arguments[0].width>0 && arguments[0].height>0);", image)
    assert image_check is True, "The image is not displayed"
```

How is it possible to get `@pytest.mark.parametrize` fixture working? I'm not familiar with pytest. Or maybe there is another options to do this parametrized test?

Answer (score 1):

As described in [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/reference.html#pytest-mark-parametrize), the `argvalues` parameter of the `parametrize` object does not accept a callable, so you cannot use it as you wrote with the `get_images_list(driver)` call.

However, you can use the `pytest_generate_tests` hook function to achieve what you want, as described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example).

Something like this could work for you:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc, driver):
    if "image" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        images_list = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('img')")
        metafunc.parametrize("image", images_list)


def test_images(driver, image):
    driver.get('https://openweathermap.org/')
    image_check = driver.execute_script("return (arguments[0].width>0 && arguments[0].height>0);", image)
    assert image_check is True, "The image is not displayed"
```